# How can I get all unique tags from an array with lodash?

Tags: vue.js, lodash

Im using Vuejs and lodash and particular lodash to try and get all uniqe tags for question in my very simple questions "app". But for some reason lodash returs all of the tags, not the uniqe ones. This is how I have design the array of questions and tags (might be a better way but dunno).

```
created() {
  this.tags = _.chain(this.fragor).map('tags').uniq().value()
},
data: function() {
    return {
        tags:[],
        fragor:[
        {
            'fraga': "Question 1",
            'svar' : "This is this explanation",
            'tags' : ['knowledge'],
        },
        {
            'fraga': "Question 2",
            'svar' : "This is this explanation for question 2",
            'tags' : ['knowledge', 'code'],
        },
        {
            'fraga': "Question 3",
            'svar' : "This is this explanation for question 3",
            'tags' : ['code'],
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

`tags` is return `[ "knowledge" ] [ "knowledge", "code" ] [ "code" ]` when the expected result should be `['knowledge', 'code']`. How can i achive this with lodash and vue?

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb9a5tcu/) for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get a single array of values by extracting 
multiple arrays use `_.flatMap()`:

```js
const fragor = [{"fraga":"Question 1","svar":"This is this explanation","tags":["knowledge"]},{"fraga":"Question 2","svar":"This is this explanation for question 2","tags":["knowledge","code"]},{"fraga":"Question 3","svar":"This is this explanation for question 3","tags":["code"]}]

const tags = _(fragor).flatMap('tags').uniq().value()

console.log(tags)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Optional without lodash:

```js
const fragor = [{ fraga: 'Question 1', svar: 'This is this explanation', tags: ['knowledge'] }, { fraga: 'Question 2', svar: 'This is this explanation for question 2', tags: ['knowledge', 'code'] }, { fraga: 'Question 3', svar: 'This is this explanation for question 3', tags: ['code'] }];

const tags = Array.from(new Set(fragor.map(f => f.tags).flat()));

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score -1):

`uniq()` is a lodash method, not a method on array.

`_(this.fragor).map('tags').uniq().value()`

---

Your way is wrong because lodash doesn't modify prototypes. Hope this might be helpful.